# i have error An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: ArgumentCountError Message: Too few arguments to function

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am making a news editing feature using CodeIgniter 3, there is also an image edit here

But has errors like the following,

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: ArgumentCountError

Message: Too few arguments to function Operator::edit_berita(), 0 passed in D:\xampp\htdocs\ui-desa\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected

Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\ui-desa\application\controllers\Operator.php

Line Number: 164

Backtrace:

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\ui-desa\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Controller Operator.php

```
public function edit_berita($id_berita) 
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Edit Berita';
        $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where(
            'user',
            ['id' => $this->session->userdata('id')],
            ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')]
        )->row_array();

           $data['berita'] = $this->model_berita->getAllBeritaById($id_berita);
        // $data['berita'] = $this->db->get('berita')->result_array();
        // $data['berita'] = $this->model_berita->getNama();

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('judul_berita', 'Judul Berita', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('isi_berita', 'Isi Berita', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/sidebar', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/topbar', $data);
            $this->load->view('operator/editberita', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        } else {

            $judul_berita     = $this->input->post('judul_berita');
            $slug_berita      = url_title($this->input->post('judul_berita'), 'dash', 'TRUE');
            $isi_berita       = $this->input->post('isi_berita');
            $tgl_berita       = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $id             = $this->session->userdata('id');

            // Cek Jika Ada Gambar Yang DiUpload
            $upload_image = $_FILES['gambar_berita'];

            if ($upload_image) {
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '2048';
                $config['upload_path'] = './gambar_berita/';

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ($this->upload->do_upload('gambar_berita')) {
                    $old_image = $data['berita']['gambar_berita'];
                    if ($old_image != 'default.jpg') {
                        unlink(FCPATH . 'gambar_berita/' . $old_image);
                    }

                    $new_image = $this->upload->data('file_name');
                    $this->db->set('gambar_berita', $new_image);
                } else {
                    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                }
            }


            $this->db->set('id_berita', $id_berita);

            $data = array(
                'judul_berita' => $judul_berita, 
                'isi_berita' => $isi_berita
            );

            $this->db->where($data); 
            $this->db->update('berita');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success" role ="alert"> Berita Berhasil di Reposting </div>');
            redirect('operator/berita');
        }
    }
```

Model model_berita.php

```
public function getAllBeritaById($id_berita)
  {
    return $this->db->get_where('berita', ['id_berita' => $id_berita])->row_array();
  }
```

View edit_berita.php

```
<!-- CK Editor 4 -->
 <script src="<?= base_url('ckeditor/'); ?>ckeditor.js"></script>
 <script src="<?= base_url('ckeditor/'); ?>samples/js/sample.js"></script>
 <link href="<?= base_url('ckeditor/'); ?>samples/css/samples.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="<?= base_url('ckeditor/'); ?>samples/toolbarconfigurator/lib/codemirror/neo.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- Begin Page Content -->
 <div class="container-fluid">

     <!-- Page Heading -->
     <h1 class="h3 mb-4 text-gray-800">

         <?= $title; ?></h1>

     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg">

             <?php if (validation_errors()) :  ?>
                 <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                     <?= validation_errors(); ?>
                 </div>
             <?php endif; ?>

             <?= $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?>

             <?= form_open_multipart('operator/edit_berita') ?>

             <form action="" method="post">

                 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $berita['id_berita']; ?>">

                 <div class="modal-body">
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <small>Masukkan Judul Berita</small>
                         <input type="text" value="<?= $berita['judul_berita']; ?>" class="form-control" id="judul_berita" name="judul_berita" placeholder="Judul Berita..." required>
                     </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                         <small>Masukkan Isi Berita</small>
                         <textarea class="form-control" name="isi_berita" id="editor" required><?= $berita['isi_berita']; ?></textarea>
                     </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                         <label for="gambar_berita">Ganti Gambar Berita</label>
                         <div class="col-sm-12">
                             <div class="row">
                                 <div class="col-sm-3">
                                     <img src="<?= base_url('gambar_berita/') . $berita['gambar_berita']; ?>" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Gambar Berita">
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-sm-9">
                                     <div class="custom-file">
                                         <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="gambar_berita" name="gambar_berita">
                                         <label class="custom-file-label" for="gambar_berita">Choose File</label>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>

                     </div>
<br>
                     <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Reset</button>
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>

                 </div>
             </form>

         </div>
     </div>

 </div>
 <!-- /.container-fluid -->

 </div>
 <!-- End of Main Content -->

 <script>
     initSample();
 </script>
```

I've tried a number of ways, but it's still an error too. Please help so that my news update feature can work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well your error clearly states that your method.

```
public function edit_berita($id_berita)
```

is expecting a parameter, which you have named $id_berita.

I cannot tell why you decided to have a parameter in this method, so I can only make some suggestions to help you solve your issue.

From what I can gather from your supplied code you could try the following options...

**Option 1:**
From what I can tell from your form, you are posting this as a hidden input, so you should be retrieving it from the Post Data.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $berita['id_berita']; ?>">
```

So your method should become...

```
public function edit_berita() 
{
    $id_berita = $this->input->post('id'); // This needs to be validated

// The rest of your code below here...
}
```

But I would be validating that value to see if it exists before processing anything else.

Personally, I would be naming it as id_berita in your form to keep things matched up to avoid mistakes.

**Option 2:**
Another option would be to modify your form_open_mulitpart from

```
<?= form_open_multipart('operator/edit_berita') ?>
```

To include the id to pass in as a parameter

```
<?= form_open_multipart('operator/edit_berita/'.$berita['id_berita']) ?>
```

You will have to check that by inspecting your HTML Source using your Browsers "View Source" and inspect the HTML to see that it has ended up in the right place.

That will let you use your existing method

```
public function edit_berita($id_berita)
```

But again, you would need to validate that the passed in $id_berita is correct.

Which ever way you go, is your choice. You just need to read through your code and understand it a bit better.

I hope that gives you some guidance.